# SQL Select FOR XML PATH - Combine ordering and concatenate string with increasing counter

Tags: sql, for-xml-path

I am trying to get from the following SQL table

```
CODE , FILENAME     , ORDER
xxxx , Noimage.jpg  , 0 
xxxx , yyyy.jpg     , 2
xxxx , zzzz.jpg     , 1
xxxx , aaaa.jpg     , 3
```

the following result --> p1=zzzz.jpg&p2=yyyy.jpg&p3=aaaa.jpg

I have tried

```
SELECT STUFF((SELECT '&' + FILENAME
            FROM MYTABLE
            WHERE IMAGEORDER<>0
            FOR XML PATH('')) ,1,1,'') AS Txt
```

but i cant figure out how can i combine the ordering and based on ordering to contacatenate the p1 , p2 ,p3

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to order the rows:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (Code VARCHAR(255), Filename VARCHAR(255), ImageOrder INT)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('xxxx', 'Noimage.jpg', 0),
('xxxx', 'yyyy.jpg', 2),
('xxxx', 'zzzz.jpg', 1),
('xxxx', 'aaaa.jpg', 3)
 
SELECT REPLACE(
  (SELECT CAST('&p' + CAST(ImageOrder AS varchar) + '=' + Filename AS VARCHAR(MAX))
  FROM @t
  WHERE ImageOrder <> 0
  ORDER BY ImageOrder
  FOR XML PATH (''))
  , 'amp;', '') AS Txt
```

Which will give you the result:

```
&p1=zzzz.jpg&p2=yyyy.jpg&p3=aaaa.jpg
```

Comment: Thank you very much , but what about the leading '&' ? The only way to avoid it i suppose is using sth like substring(txt,1,len(txt)-1) in all of the above .. correct ?

Answer (score 0):

Your stuff needs meta data else the output will be formatted as xml. Also, if you are using version 2016+ you can use the [STUFF()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function to achieve the same functionality. I added a normalization CTE to add the calculated P1,P2..PX values based on IMAGEORDER.

```
;WITH Normalized AS
(
    SELECT      
        '&P'+CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY IMAGEORDER) AS NVARCHAR(10))+'='+FILENAME AS Item,
        IMAGEORDER
    FROM
        MYTABLE
    WHERE
        IMAGEORDER<>0
)


SELECT STUFF((SELECT Item
            FROM Normalized ORDER BY IMAGEORDER             
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','varchar(max)') ,1,1,'') AS Txt
```